# How to send List as body in request using spring rest Template

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

How to send List as body in request using spring rest Template. I have a list with multiple filename. List need to send in json fromat in body of request. 
I am trying as below written code but getting exception as mentioned below -

Possible solutions:

```
postForObject(java.net.URI, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Class)
postForObject(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Class, [Ljava.lang.Object;)
postForObject(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Class, java.util.Map)



 def demo(def url, def returnObject, List filenames) {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<List, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<List, String>>(filenames, headers);
            methodcall.postForObject(url, request, returnObject)
        }
```

Comment: What's your exception? Also: The code of your method is not Java...

Comment: yup, this is groovy syntax. Actually I want to send a request to restfull service and passing list as body and application content as application/json. How to do it.

Comment: Do you really want to post a list as the request body? Usually you would just post one Java object which gets converted to a JSON object by the REST template.

Comment: ok..could you please let me know your approach in details

Comment: or can we send list as string array?